# Tridiagonal matrix has real eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to prove that if $A$ is real $n \times n$ and tridiagonal such that $a_{i,i+1}a_{i+1,i} > 0$, $i = 1,2,...,n − 1$ then there is a real diagonal matrix D such that $DAD^{−1}$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
d_1 & a_{1,2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{2,1} & d_2 & a_{2,3} & 0, 0 \\
0 & a_{3,2} & d_3 & a_{3,4} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{4,3} & d_4 & a_{4,5} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{5,4} & d_5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(u,v,w,x,y)$

$DAD^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
d_1 & a_{1,2}\frac uv & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
a_{2,1}\frac vu & d_2 & a_{2,3}\frac vw & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a_{3,2}\frac wv & d_3 & a_{3,4}\frac wx & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a_{4,3}\frac xw & d_4 & a_{4,5}\frac xy \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a_{5,4}\frac yx & d_5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

So you have $\dfrac {u^2}{v^2}=\dfrac{a_{2,1}}{a_{1,2}}>0$ and similarly for other coefficients, so you can take the square root and define the coefficients of $D$.

#### A possible way to redact it:

$A=L+\Delta+U$ where

- $L$ for lower diagonal coefficients $a_{i+1,i}$
- $\Delta$ for diagonal coefficients $d_i$
- $U$ for upper diagonal coefficients $a_{i,i+1}$

Then $DAD^{-1}=DLD^{-1}+\Delta+DUD^{-1}\quad$ since diagonal matrices commute.

The matrix is symetrical if $(DLD^{-1})^T=D^{-1}L^TD=DUD^{-1}\iff L^TD^2=D^2U$

Where $(L^TD^2)_i=a_{i+1,i}\;x_{i+1,i+1}^2$ and $(D^2U)_i=a_{i,i+1}\;x_{i,i}^2$